# What does sentiwordnet 3.0 result signify?

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

What does the result of sentiwordnett signify?.

If the value given for good is 0.6337,does it mean the probability that the word good is positive is 0.6337 or does it mean the word good has a weightage of 0.6337?if it is the weightage given,then value of extraordinary should be greater than good but value given to extraordinary is only 0.272727 .

and the format of sentiwordnet is

## POS   ID  PosScore    NegScore    SynsetTerms Gloss

How exactly is the final result caluculated? (using the demo code http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/code/SentiWordNetDemoCode.java)

What does the term sense signify?(the number after #)

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, the process mainly consists of two steps:

- a semi-supervised learning step: they start from two sets of 7 sense which are paradigmatically positive and negative and using the WordNet relations they spread positivity and negativity accordingly.
- a random-walk step: by considering WordNet a graph they perform a random-walk algorithm in which the labels `positive` and `negative` can possibly change, till convergence.

You can find more details about how the final score is computer in the [related scientific paper](http://www.esuli.it/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/LREC10.pdf).

The #sense field refers to the numeric sense ID in WordNet, since SentiWordNet is based on it.