# What is the meaning of sense number in SentiWordNet?

Tags: sentiment-analysis, senti-wordnet

I want to use SentiWordNet for my project and I could not figure out what does the **sense number** do? Here is a part of SentiWordNet's word list;

> ## POS ID  PosScore    NegScore    SynsetTerms Gloss
>
> a 00002730    0   0   acroscopic#1    facing or on the side toward the apex
>
> a 00002843    0   0   basiscopic#1    facing or on the side toward the base
>
> a 00003829    0.25    0   parturient#2    giving birth; "a parturient heifer"

Here is the explanation of SentiWordNet from its word list document;

> The pair (POS,ID) uniquely identifies a WordNet (3.0) synset. The
> values PosScore and NegScore are the positivity and negativity score
> assigned by SentiWordNet to the synset. The objectivity score can be
> calculated as: ObjScore = 1 - (PosScore + NegScore) SynsetTerms column
> reports the terms, with sense number, belonging to the synset
> (separated by spaces).

I also found a related question here but I did not understand **the feature of the sense number** from the answer. Here is the related question's link: [What does sentiwordnet 3.0 result signify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863413/what-does-sentiwordnet-3-0-result-signify)

*My question is:* How can I use this **sense number** part in my code? **What does it do exactly?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [lookup "parturient" in WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=parturient&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=00) you'll see two meanings are shown. These are parturient#1 and  parturient#2 respectively.

In that case the difference is rather subtle. But, for instance, the word ["field" has lots of senses](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=field&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=00), and you might care which one is being referred to.

You would use them if you then start looking at the semantic relations of that word. E.g. the hypernym of field#4 is "knowledge domain", whereas the hypernym of of field#1 is "tract" (piece of land).

A classic example when considering sentiment is to [compare suck#2 and suck#4](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=suck&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=000000000000000000000) in the context of talking about a vacumn cleaner! E.g. "This cleaner really sucks#4 as it hardly sucks#2 at all."

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Now it is much more clear to me.